# Force `stack` to rebuild an installed package

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I often install a package which depends on external libraries and manage to move those external libraries to other locations afterwards, so that compiled programs exit with a loader error.

In those cases I just want stack to rebuild an already installed package, but I don't see how that is possible. `stack install --force-dirty` doesn't seem to work, as it just tries to rebuild the project in the current working directory.

---

Recent example:

I'd liked to see whether `regex-pcre` requires a C library not present on Windows systems, so I hit `stack install regex-pcre`. That went fine, but then I realized I installed `mingw-w64-x86_64-pcre` via `stack`s `pacman` prior to this. I removed it again via `pacman -R` and tried to run `stack install regex-pcre` again, which did not rebuild it. Neither did adding `--force-dirty` work for the above reason.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update:**

Based on @Michael Snoyman's comment just using this command should be enough to remove the package:

```
stack exec -- ghc-pkg unregister --force regex-pcre
```

**Original Answer:**

I don't know if it's the sanctioned way to do it, but it seems to work. Here is a synopsis:

1. Locate the `ghc-pkg` program for the version of GHC you are using
2. Locate the package-db directory for your resolver version
3. Run `$ghcpkg --package-db $pkgdb unregister --force <package>`
4. Also remove the package file from stack's `precompiled` directory

Suppose the package we want to remove is `zlib-0.5.4.2`.

**Locating ghc-pkg**

Under ~/.stack/programs find the ghc-pkg program appropriate for your compiler version, e.g. `~/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-7.10.2/bin/ghc-pkg`. Call this `$ghcpkg`

**Locating the package db**

Under ~/.stack/snapshots find the `pkgdb` directory for the resolver you are using, e.g. `~/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-3.1/7.10.2/pkgdb`. Call this `$pkgdb`.

**Unregister the package**

Run:

```
$ghcpkg --package-db $pkgdb unregister --force zlib-0.5.4.2
```

Ignore any warnings about broken or breaking packages.

You can check to see if your package is registered or not with this command:

```
$ghcpkg --package-db $pkgdb list | grep zlib
```

**Remove the package from the `precompiled` directory**

Under `~/.stack/precompiled` locate any directories named `zlib-0.5.4.2` and remove the one for your the relevant version of GHC:

```
find ~/.stack/precompiled -name 'zlib-*'
/bin/rm -rf ...
```

**Reinstall the package**

```
stack --resolver=... install zlib
```

Stack should report that it is rebuilding the package.

Comment: You can probably get away with just `stack exec -- ghc-pkg unregister pkgname`

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman @erikR does `stack exec -- ghc-pkg unregister pkgname` work with the newer versions of stack (the ones which use pantry)?

Comment: Pantry shouldn't affect it

Comment: I believe with Stack 2, you now need to manipulate the sqlite file. I got it working like: `sqlite3 ~/.stack/stack.sqlite3 "DELETE FROM precompiled_cache WHERE library LIKE '%pkgdb/zlib-%'"`.

@MichaelSnoyman do you think we should open an issue on Stack to make the process of unregistering a dependency easier? For some background, we have to do this every time the `icu4c` package updates on brew, because `text-icu` will be linked to an old non-existent version of the icu4c dylibs