# Where is the source of `GHC.Paths.*` value came from?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am running `stack` version 1.1.2 x86_64 hpack-0.14.1

```
$ stack exec which ghc
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-5.10 from implicit global project's config file: /home/wisut/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
/home/wisut/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc
```

but when using `stack ghci` with `GHC.Paths` it is return the wrong path

```
$ stack ghci
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-5.10 from implicit global project's config file: /home/wisut/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
Error parsing targets: The specified targets matched no packages. Perhaps you need to run 'stack init'?
Warning: build failed, but optimistically launching GHCi anyway
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Ok, modules loaded: none.
Prelude> GHC.Paths.ghc
"/usr/bin/ghc-7.10.3"
```

I am running Arch linux with ghc 8.0.1 therefor there is no ghc-7 avaliable outside `stack`

```
[wisut@earth ~]$ which ghc
/usr/bin/ghc
[wisut@earth ~]$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.1
[wisut@earth ~]$ ls -al /usr/bin/ghc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 May 24 18:28 /usr/bin/ghc -> ghc-8.0.1
```

Looking at GHC.Paths source, I have no idea where the value are from. Is it the ENV vars?

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

module GHC.Paths (
        ghc, ghc_pkg, libdir, docdir
  ) where

libdir, docdir, ghc, ghc_pkg :: FilePath

libdir  = GHC_PATHS_LIBDIR
docdir  = GHC_PATHS_DOCDIR

ghc     = GHC_PATHS_GHC
ghc_pkg = GHC_PATHS_GHC_PKG
```

Running `stack exec env` didn't see anything.

```
$ stack exec env | grep -i ghc
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
GHC_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/wisut/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/installx86_64-linux/lts-5.10/7.10.3/pkgdb:/home/wisut/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-5.10/7.10.3/pkgdb:/home/wisut/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/package.conf.d
PATH=/home/wisut/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-5.10/7.10.3/bin:/home/wisut/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-5.10/7.10.3/bin:/home/wisut/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/bin:/home/wisut/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

How can I fix the wrong value? How to to config `stack` to make `GHC.Paths` return the correct one?

**UPD**
I tried running `stack` with `--no-system-ghc` and it didn't make any difference.
I tried to remove my `~/.cabal` and `~/.stack` folders. I had to do `stack setup`, and after `stack` re-installed the compiler it doesn't give me that wrong path, but it doesn't give me *any* path, the output of that command is now empty.
I have nothing special in any of `Setup.hs` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right, the `GHC_` variables are CPP definitions coming from [custom `Setup.hs`](https://github.com/simonmar/ghc-paths/blob/7d0695ccd905f2d3878848990560efa435873549/Setup.hs#L55-L58):

```
let buildinfo = emptyBuildInfo{
         cppOptions = ["-DGHC_PATHS_GHC_PKG=" ++ show c_ghc_pkg,
                       "-DGHC_PATHS_GHC=" ++ show c_ghc,
                       "-DGHC_PATHS_LIBDIR=" ++ show libdir,
                       "-DGHC_PATHS_DOCDIR=" ++ show docdir ]
       }
```

---

About your problem with wrong path, try to run `stack --no-system-ghc ghci`. If it still shows `"/usr/bin/ghc-7.10.3"` for GHC paths, then I suspect that you **had** GHC there when you compiled `ghc-paths` for GHC-7.10.3, and as `stack` is quite good in not rebuilding stuff, the old version of `ghc-paths` is still there. I don't know a way to rebuild a package in a snapshot, other then whiping `~/.stack` and starting over; which might be a good idea. if you changed you global GHC stuff.

There is a related issue: [Stop using system-ghc silently](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2221).

Comment: To force stck to rebuild a package - have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37237777/866915

Comment: I tried with `--no-system-ghc` and it doesn't make any difference. I tried to remove my `~/.cabal` and `~/.stack` folders and after `stack` re-installed the compiler it doesn't give me that wrong path, but it doesn't give me _any_ path, the output of that command is now empty.
I have nothing special in any of `Setup.hs` either.