# How to uninstall a Haskell package installed with stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How can I uninstall a Haskell package installed globally with stack tool?

`stack --help` shows that uninstall command is deprecated.

```
  uninstall                DEPRECATED: This command performs no actions, and is
                           present for documentation only
```

Comment: Possible related quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236892/force-stack-to-rebuild-an-installed-package/37237777#37237777

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As `stack --help` says, uninstall doesn't do anything. You can read about this [on the stack github](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/361) where this feature was requested, but it ended up being closed without the desire to add the behavior to stack, for various reasons. So, officially, there is no way to use stack to uninstall a package.

To remove a package that stack installed, you need to manually do so. This entails using ghc-pkg unregister and then finding the location of the package on your system and removing it via another tool or simply `rm`. For example,

```
stack install <package name>
# Now remove the package
ghc-pkg unregister <pkg-id>
cd /path/to/stack/packages # This could be something like ~/.local/bin, but is configuration dependent
rm <package name>
```

Comment: Packages installed by stack are located deep within ~/.stack/snapshots/...

Comment: @ErikR That is configuration dependent. Some configurations may go to .local, others may go to .stack, others may go to .stack-work

Comment: what is <pkg-id>, how do I find it ?

Comment: @franssu `ghc-pkg field <package-name> id`

Comment: Sometimes you have to do `stack exec ghc-pkg unregister ...`.

Comment: i don't have ghc-pkg