# How To uninstall a stack package

Tags: haskell, uninstallation, haskell-stack

I installed yesod via

> stack install yesod-bin

And it installed it on my $HOME/.local/bin directory, I'm trying to uninstall it over stack uninstall yesod-bin, but I'm not being successful, wonder if I just delete it, it'll be enough to getting it off my system.

Comment: No, deleting the binary won't reverse all the effects that `stack install` had. And unfortunately, as far as I know, neither stack nor cabal has a clean story for uninstalling.

Comment: `stack` doesn’t contain a command for uninstallation. See https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/361 for more details about why this is the case. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636436/how-to-uninstall-a-haskell-package-installed-with-stack for a manual way to remove a package, for if you really really want to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uninstall a Haskell package installed with stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636436/how-to-uninstall-a-haskell-package-installed-with-stack)