# How to uninstall packages with spago?

Tags: purescript, spago

What is the spago equivalent of `yarn remove` or `npm uninstall`?

Is there [no way to remove packages as with Haskell stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38639959/9130688)? If so, what are the steps to remove a package manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the package make from `spago.dhall`, that's it.

`npm` has to have a special command for this, because `node` doesn't care what's in `package.json`, it will pick up any packages that are in `node_modules`. This means that `npm uninstall` has to remove the package from `package.json`, but then also delete it from `node_modules`, was well as all its dependencies.

Spago, on the other hand, doesn't need to do this, because `spago.dhall` is the single source of truth. Even if the package files are present inside the `.spago` directory, they will not be used in compilation unless the package is also mentioned in `spago.dhall`

This also works the other way around: if you just add a package to `spago.dhall`, Spago will automatically download it next time you run any Spago command.

Comment: Does it mean it will automatically remove the packages not present in `spago.dhall` when i run any spago command?

Comment: No, it will not. Can you clarify why exactly you need to remove them from the disk?

Comment: I just want to claim disk space, guess I can manually remove the package name, `rm -r .spago` and `spago` again to claim disk space.

Comment: Are you really that limited on disk space? Why?